# Removing Element from Copy of list also removes it from original list

Tags: python, list

`brothers` is a list of lists, each sublist is 1 or 2 elements (ie. `[["hi" "bob"] ["hi"] ["hi"]]`

```
temp = brothers.copy()
temp[0].remove(temp[0][0])
```

when I run this code, the element I remove in `temp`  is also removed in `brothers`. How do I change this so that `temp` changes but `brothers` does not?

Comment: `.copy` makes a new outer list, but the inner objects are _not_ copied.  Use `.deepcopy()` for that.

Answer (score 1):

use `deepcopy()`

```
import copy
temp = copy.deepcopy(brothers)
temp[0].remove(temp[0][0])
```